# JS Coding error! Regarding external link not running extra code

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, external

```js
if (confirm("By clicking Ok, you agree to letting us log your IP! If you say Cancel, you will be sent back to Google's homepage!") != true) {
  window.location.replace("http://google.com");
  console.log("Website.js, loaded! No ERROR!");
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#pd {
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
ul {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px
}
#form {
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
#clientIP {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1></h1> 
  <p id="clientIP"></p>
  <div id="pd">
    <p></p>
    <h1></h1>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <br>
      <li></li>
      <br>
      <li></li>
      <br>
      <li></li>
      <br>
      <li></li>
      <br>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Website.css' />
  <script src="Website.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.l2.io/ip.js?var=myip"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("clientIP").innerHTML = "Your IP is - " + myip;
    console.log("File that retrives IP has been run! No ERROR!")
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

So I am paranoid, hence the missing text,but the error is that when everything is run and working, Website.js' log does not appear! Its bugging me! Website.js is the JS code..... Yes, but I am annoyed that the log doesn't appear when I inspect element!

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the location of the window, and therefore replacing all of your code with that of `http://google.com` before the `log` method is called. Your script never gets to run this command because your script has been replaced during the previous command, and thus never gets to subsequent ones.

Comment: I feel really dumb, but THANK YOU! LOL That line was supposed to be in an else statement!

Comment: @SeandaPotato Haha no worries. I feel dumb too. If I had just scrolled right in your code I would have noticed that and been able to give more specific advice.